# How Intercept a super method in a specific instance

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a class called ControladorImpressaoDAV that extends ControladorBase:

```
public class ControladorImpressaoDAV extends ControladorBase {
    .
    .
    .
}

public abstract class ControladorBase implements IProcessamentoDispatcher, EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent> {
    .
    .
    .
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent evento) {
        StatusRetorno status = (StatusRetorno) evento.getSource().getValue();
        despacharProcessamento(StatusProcessamento.FINALIZADO, status);
        if (status == StatusRetorno.SUCESSO)
            exibirMensagemSucesso();
        else
            exibirMensagemErro(status);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

as the behavior is the same when the JavaFX calls **handle** method, there is no need in override this method in ControladorImpressaoDAV. However I can intercept this method, when in a ControladorImpressaoDAV instance, only when I override this method:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.hrgi.pdv.controladores.ControladorImpressaoDAV.handle(..))")
protected void terminouImprimirDAV(){}
```

Is there a way I can intercept the handle method only when it is in a ControladorImpressaoDAV instance without override the handle method?

Answer (score 0):

Extend your base class something like this

```
public abstract class ControladorBase implements IProcessamentoDispatcher, EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent> {
    .
    .
    .
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent evento) {
        handled(evento);
        StatusRetorno status = (StatusRetorno) evento.getSource().getValue();
        despacharProcessamento(StatusProcessamento.FINALIZADO, status);
        if (status == StatusRetorno.SUCESSO)
            exibirMensagemSucesso();
        else
            exibirMensagemErro(status);
    }
    protected void handled(WorkerStateEvent evento){};
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Now any subclass can get information about handled event if needed by oveeriding method.